# array sums and statistics

Tags: python

Input:

```
a[0] = [0, 1, 2]
a[1] = [0, 2, 2]
a[2] = [100, 200, 300]
```

Output1:

```
output1
>> [100, 203, 304]
```

Output2:

```
output2
>> [{0:2, 100:1}, {1:1, 2:1, 200:1}, {2:2, 300:1}]
```

In other words, output1 calculate the sum of each column, and output2 statistics the occurrence of each number in each column.

(Actually, a is a matrix of 4000*400000)
Does anyone have ideas how to do this efficiently in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for output1 you can calculate sum for each row of transposed matrix:

```
map(sum, zip(*a))
```

for output2 you can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) applied to each column:

```
from collections import Counter
output = [Counter(col) for col in zip(*a)]
```

Or:

```
output = map(Counter, zip(*a))
```

Comment: +1 you could've used map in the second case too, like: `map(Counter, zip(*a))`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2], [100, 200, 300]]
##output1
print map(sum, zip(*a))
##output2
s = []
for p in zip(*a):
    u = {}
    for e in p:
        u.setdefault(e, 0)
        u[e] += 1
    s.append(u)
print s
```